# How to tell if a particular .NET assembly was written in C# or F#?

Tags: decompilation, .net, c#

The motivation for this question is that I used JetBrains dotPeek to decompile an .exe written in F#, but the output project directory produced C# code.

Why does decompiling an F# assembly produce C# code?

I know that both languages get JIT-compiled from MSIL to native code, which may make it difficult to definitively say what the original language was.

Despite this, are there reliable methods for distinguishing C# binaries from F# ones via static analysis? Dynamic analysis?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does decompiling an F# assembly produce C# code?

It doesn't. It produces IL code which then can be interpreted as C#, F# or VB.NET. dotPeek doesn't allow you to use any other language for previewing but for example [dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy), [ILSpy](https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy) allow you to pick your favourite one. Just wondering if there's any tools that allows F#. Not sure/haven't seen one.

> Despite this, are there reliable methods for distinguishing C# binaries from F# ones via static analysis? Dynamic analysis?

There are some hints that can guide you. Check the references. If something is referencing the `FSharp.Core` then probably was written in F#. On the other hand if it doesn't probably it was not :)

F#'s dlls usually have a lot of attributes put on classes like `[FSharpInterfaceDataVersion]` or `[CompilationMappingAttribute]` being used. Check them.

There's one more thing. F# compiler is capable of using a [tail-recursion](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2011/07/08/tail-calls-in-f/) by generating [tailcall opcode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.tailcall(v=vs.110).aspx) which is not the case with C# (at least for now). That could be an indicator. But it could be also manually crafted to use it after being written completely in C#.